# Checkboxes not working with javascript function

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, checkbox, criteria-filter

I am trying to make a dynamic filter on accounts. What I want to achieve is to show only the records where the checkboxes are true.

The issue I have is that my function is not working based on a checkbox selection.

In my lightning debug console I see the events being logged but no actions.

Controller

```
    public class accountList {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAllAccounts()
    {
        List<Account> lstacc=[select Name,BillingCity from Account where BillingCity != null];
        return lstacc;
    }
}
```

Component

```
<aura:component controller="accountList">
    <aura:attribute name="allaccounts" type="Account[]" description="All accounts" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.fillAccount}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="name" type="string" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="text" type="string" /> 
    <aura:attribute name="value" type="string"/> 
    <aura:attribute name="selectedvalues" type="string" />
    <aura:attribute name="SelectedCity" type="List[]" />
    <aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <div class="container">       
        <div>
            <div style="background-color: #7f7e8a;height: 20px;"></div>    
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.allaccounts}" var="account">
                <article class="slds-card">
                    <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                        <header class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                            <div class="slds-media__body slds-truncate">
                                <h2>
                                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset">
                                        <span class="slds-text-heading--small">{!account.Name}</span>
                                    </a>
                                </h2>
                            </div>
                        </header>
                    </div>
                    <div class="slds-card__body">{!account.BillingCity}</div>
                </article>
            </aura:iteration>
        </div>
    </div>   
    <aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.allaccounts}" indexVar="indx">
        <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" text="{!a.BillingCity}" name="{!indx}" label="{!a.BillingCity}" change="{!c.selectoptionvalue}"/>
    </aura:iteration>
    <aura:iteration items="{!v.selectedvalues}" var="account">
        <article class="slds-card">
            <div class="slds-card__header slds-grid">
                <header class="slds-media slds-media--center slds-has-flexi-truncate">
                    <div class="slds-media__body slds-truncate">
                        <h2>
                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slds-text-link--reset">
                                <span class="slds-text-heading--small">{!account.Name}</span>
                            </a>
                        </h2>
                    </div>
                </header>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-card__body">{!account.BillingCity}</div>
        </article>
    </aura:iteration>
</aura:component>
```

Javascript Controller

```
({      
    fillAccount : function(component, event, helper) {
        var action = component.get("c.getAllAccounts");
        action.setCallback(this,function(a){
            var state=a.getState();
            if(state == "SUCCESS"){
                component.set("v.allaccounts",a.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
    selectoptionvalue :function(component,event,helper){
        var temp=component.get("v.selectedvalues");
        var SelectedCity=component.get("v.SelectedCity");
        var accountdetails = component.get("v.allaccounts");
        temp = [];


        var check = component.find("checkbox")
        var SelectedCity = [];
        if(check.get("v.value")== true){
            SelectedCity.push({'ids':check.get("v.name"),'name':check.get("v.text"),'value':check.get("v.value")});    }

        if(check.get("v.value") == false){
            for(var j=0;j<SelectedCity.length;j++){
                if(SelectedCity[j].ids == check.get("v.name")){
                    var index = j;
                }
            }
            SelectedCity.splice(index,1);
        }
        component.set("v.SelectedCity",SelectedCity);      
        var accountdetails = component.get("v.allaccounts");        
        for(var i=0;i<accountdetails.length;i++){
            for(var k=0;k<SelectedCity.length;k++){
                if(accountdetails[i].BillingCity == SelectedCity[k].name){
                    temp.push(accountdetails[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: please avoid deleting and reposting questions in order to draw more attention to your posts. Thanks

Comment: @glls As nobody could answer my previous question and I am trying another approach I deleted the post as it doesnt add to the community. This post is a total different question but thanks for pointing this out. Furthermore It would be nice to offer some help to solve this issue but thanks anyway.

Comment: I'm pretty confident that you could modify your posts to include minimal code samples with a specific problem description, debug info, what you have tried to correct the behavior and point out specific code lines that are causing you a headache.  As is, I personally dont feel like going through all your code and pointing out what changes you should make. "Maybe" someone else will...

Comment: Another Pointer (which has been mentioned to you in the past in comments of other of your post(s) ) you should add exception and error handling to your code, and more logging for you to better understand what goes on when you executing your code.

Comment: @glls I completely disagree with you as I already pointed out that the issue is the combination of my checkbox and function. I added all the code so its easy to reproduce. Furthermore your answers do not point in anyway to for example were to look at and isn't very constructive as is the purpose of the exchange. I am not a pro like you to precisely know where to look at if I would I would'n be asking.

Comment: none of my comments are answers, simply pointers on improving your post quality, some that have been pointed out in the past and being reiterated here.  here is anotehr one, comments in your code will help others better understand what you are attemtping to do when going through your code.

Comment: @glls Ok thanks Ill take your advice as a learning process

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72350/discussion-between-glls-and-thomas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I find form your post is that there are two if block out of which the only one will execute.

```
 if(event.getSource().get("v.value")){
    SelectedCity.push({'ids':event.getSource().get("v.name"),'name':event.getSource().get("v.text"),'value':event.getSource().get("v.value")});
}
if(event.getSource().get("v.value") == false){
    for(var j=0;j<SelectedCity.length;j++){
        if(SelectedCity[j].ids == event.getSource().get("v.name")){
            var index = j;
        }
    }
     SelectedCity.splice(index,1);
 }
```

and each time you click on a checkbox controller function "selectoptionvalue" will set SelectedCity to an empty list.
Maybe that is the issue in your code.
Please have a look at it deeply may this will help you.